# HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError: execution expired

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

**ENVIRONMENT:**

xcode path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer 
xcode version:  Xcode 7.3 
calabash-ios version: 0.18.2 
run_loop version: 2.0.9 
simulator:  iPhone 6s Plus (9.3)

Started my app manually from Xcode and did:

```
$ curl http://localhost:37265/version
{
    "device_family": "iPhone",
    "outcome": "SUCCESS",
    "server_port": 37265,
    "simulator_devic e": "iPhone",
    "simulator": "CoreSimulator 209.19 - Device: iPhone 6s Plus -    Runtime: iOS 9.3 (13E230) - DeviceType: iPhone 6s Plus",
    "app_name": "SOTesters",
    "app_version": "11.2",
    "screen_dimensions": {
        "sample": 1,
        "height": 2208,
        "width": 1242,
        "scale": 3
    },
    "git": {
        "revision": "68026d3",
        "remote_origin": "git@github.com:calabash\/calabash-ios-server.git",
        "branch": "master"
    },
    "device_name": "iPhone Simulator",
    "4inch": false,
    "app_id": "com.goinstant.internal.SOTesters",
    "form_factor": "iphone 6+",
    "system": "x86_64",
    "version": "0.18.2",
    "iOS_version": "9.3",
    "short_version_string": "11.2",
    "ios_version": "9.3",
    "iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad": false,
    "model_identifier": "iPhone8,2",
    "app_base_sdk": "iphonesimulator9.3"
}
```

**Steps to reproduce** 
1. Build app to iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) simulator 
2. Launch DEBUG=1 DEBUG_HTTP=1 DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 6s Plus (9.3)'calabash-ios console

irb(main):003:0> start_test_server_in_background

```
EXEC: xcrun strings /Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOTesters.app/SOTesters
INFO: Detected app at path:
 INFO: /Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOTesters.app
 INFO: Modification time of app: Tue 29 Mar 2016 17:20:52 ADT
 INFO: If this is incorrect, set the APP variable and/or rebuild your app
 INFO: It is your responsibility to ensure you are testing the right app.

INFO: Using uia strategy: 'host'
DEBUG: Searching for run-loop results with glob: /Users/k/.run-loop/results/*
DEBUG: Found 6 previous run-loop results
DEBUG: Will delete 1 previous run-loop results
DEBUG: Deleted 1 previous results in 0.007448 seconds
DEBUG: Searching for instruments caches with glob:     /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments/xrtmp__*
DEBUG: Found 6 instruments caches
DEBUG: Will delete 1 instruments caches
DEBUG: Deleted 1 instruments caches in 0.002827 seconds
DEBUG: Simulator instruction set 'x86_64' is compatible with '["x86_64"]'
DEBUG: Deleting /Users/k/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DDB1E8ED-    025F-40E5-AF6C-1A99C30729B9/data/tmp/instruments_cvg4z3/stdio.pipe
DEBUG: Installed app is the same as #<APP: /Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOTesters.app>
DEBUG: Launching #<Simulator: iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) DDB1E8ED-025F-40E5-AF6C-1A99C30729B9 x86_64> with:
EXEC: xcrun open -g -a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID DDB1E8ED-025F-40E5-AF6C-1A99C30729B9
DEBUG: Waiting for simulator to stabilize with timeout: 30
DEBUG: Simulator stable after 4.394763 seconds
DEBUG: Waited a total of 6.394763 seconds for simulator to stabilize
DEBUG: Took 6.519767 seconds to launch the simulator
2016-03-29 22:23:23 -0300 [RunLoop:debug]:
{
                    :app => "/Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOTesters.app",
                   :args => [],
:bundle_dir_or_bundle_id => "/Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOTesters.app",
              :bundle_id => "com.goinstant.internal.SOTesters",
          :device_target => "iPhone 6s Plus (9.3)",
            :instruments => #<Instruments 7.3>,
          :launch_method => :instruments,
         :launch_retries => 5,
               :log_file => "/Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14/run_loop.out",
              :no_launch => false,
                :no_stop => false,
     :relaunch_simulator => true,
                  :reset => false,
            :results_dir => "/Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14",
      :results_dir_trace => "/Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14/trace",
                 :script => "/Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14/_run_loop.js",
            :sdk_version => nil,
                   :udid => "iPhone 6s Plus (9.3)",
           :uia_strategy => :host,
                  :xcode => "7.3",
             :xcode_path => "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
}
EXEC: xcrun instruments -s templates

### Starting on iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) App: /Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOTesters.app ###
EXEC: xcrun instruments -s devices
2016-03-29 22:23:24 -0300 [RunLoop:debug]: xcrun instruments -w DDB1E8ED-025F-40E5-AF6C-1A99C30729B9 -D /Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14/trace -t Automation /Users/k/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOTesters.app -e UIARESULTSPATH /Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14 -e UIASCRIPT /Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14/_run_loop.js >& /Users/k/.run-loop/results/2016-03-29_22-23-14/run_loop.out
2016-03-29 22:23:24 -0300 [RunLoop:debug]: Preparation took 10.577951 seconds
2016-03-29 22:23:29 -0300 [RunLoop:debug]: Launching took 4.361413 seconds
DEBUG: It took 14.939501 seconds to launch the app
|
```

The cursor waits there and it's incomplete.

I have to ctrl+c and to return `irb>`

If I query without `start_test_server_in_background` I get timeout error

```
irb(main):001:0> query("*")
= Request

> ! CONNECT TO 10.10.10.10:37265
Retrying.. HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError: (execution expired)
= Request

`! CONNECT TO 10.10.10.10:37265
Retrying.. HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError: (execution expired)
= Request

> ! CONNECT TO 10.10.10.10:37265
Failing... HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError
HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError: execution expired
```

I basically followed all the instructions on https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version

The server version and gem version are 0.18.2 but still can't connect. I tried running on other simulator and I'm getting the same connection timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for including all relevant information.

Your `curl` is against `localhost`, but the stacktrace shows: `10.10.10.10:37265`.  These means that somewhere in your environment `DEVICE_ENDPOINT` is set to "http://10.10.10.10:37265".

Either you are starting the Calabash console with `DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://10.10.10.10:37265` or `DEVICE_ENDPOINT` has been exported in your shell.

Try:

```
$ DEVICE_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:37265" calabash-ios console
> start_test_server_in_background
```

You can check to see if `DEVICE_ENDPOINT` has been defined in your shell:

```
$ echo $DEVICE_ENDPOINT
```

Comment: Joshua, you're right. I had the $DEVICE_ENDPOINT defined in my shell to start server on real device.  I was under an impression that running simulator would not use the device endpoint. I removed it in shell and did source command and closed the terminal but it didn't work. I had to restart my machine and the issue is resolved now. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Did you `start_test_server_in_background` before running `query()` in `irb` ? There's a fairly complex attachment process that has to occur before calabash can interact with your app.

Comment: I tried `start_test_server_in_background` before running `query()` in `irb`.

Comment: Ok, then would you mind posting the full warning/error log?

Comment: I tried `start_test_server_in_background` before running `query()` in `irb`. It launches the app on simulator and it's just waiting for something. Only ctrl+c returns me to `irb>`. I can't query there so I tried the above reproducible steps to see what it actually does and I got that connection timedout error

Comment: Ok, if you run `start_test_server_in_background` and then just wait (probably a minute or two), does it give you an error/stack trace? There are some hot topics about various odd issues that may help -> https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics